# Import by file/module name in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to make a simple localization module that takes a key name and returns the localized string based on the language given. The language is one of the constants and maps to a python file that contains the string table. I want to do this dynamically at runtime. Below is my approach, but GAE does not support the imp module. Is there an alternative way to do this?

```
import logging
import imp

import localizable

LANGUAGE_EN = "en"
LANGUAGE_JP = "ja"

class Localizer(object):
    """
    Returns a localized string corresponding to unique keys
    """
    @classmethod
    def localize(cls, language = LANGUAGE_EN, key = None):
        user_language = imp.load_source("localizable.%s" % language, "/")
        if (user_language):
            return user_language.Locale.localize(key)
        else:
            logging.error("Localizable file was not found")
            return ""
```

I put the language files in localizable/en.py, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to the imp module that (I believe) should be available in GAE is `__import__()`. It's in fact what the 'import' statement calls to do the actual importing.

```
user_language = getattr(__import__('localizable.%s' % language), language)
```

or

```
user_language __import__('localizable.%s' % language, {}, globals(), [''])
```

(passing a non-empty fourth argument to `__import__` causes it to return the right-most module in the first argument, instead of the left-most. It's a little hacky, so people tend to prefer the first solution over the second.)

Comment: First solution worked perfectly, thank you. I will upvote as soon as I am able.. (apparently requires 15 rep)